# JavaFX Snapshot not capturing Label

Tags: javafx, label, javafx-2, javafx-8, snapshot

I'm making a JavaFX program that is intended to allow people to make play diagrams (for a sport). I need this program to be able to take snapshots of the diagrams. I had strange behavior in that snapshot appears to do everything I need it to, with the exception that the labels are not appearing in the snapshot.

[I need a snapshot of this diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5buhZ.png)

But when I take the snapshot and try to use it as a thumbnail image, all the labels that were letters are missing.

The strange thing is that the the label is a part of a stackpane, and the stackpane contains the circles and they are still appearing. I just don't understand why the labels aren't appearing as well.

Furthermore, I did find a work-a-round. If I can't figure out why the labels aren't appearing in the snapshot, I found if I simply change the Label's to Text objects instead...suddenly...the snapshot is working correctly!?!?

[Snapshot is missing the labels(Left Diagram) but if I use a Text object instead of a Label object the snapshot picks them up (Right Diagram)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nC985.png)

At this point I will simply change the labels to text objects, but it has been bothering me why it doesn't work with the label. Does anybody know why this behavior is occurring?

Here is the code to the object that contains the label. It extends from stackpane. The relevant object is the "labelLbl." Again, simply changing it to Text seems to fix my issue.

```
public class EditorPlayer extends StackPane {

private static final Image LEFT_SHADE_IMAGE = new Image(EditorPlayer.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("resources/leftshade.png"));
private static final Image MIDDLE_SHADE_IMAGE = new Image(EditorPlayer.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("resources/middleshade.png"));
private static final Image RIGHT_SHADE_IMAGE = new Image(EditorPlayer.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("resources/rightshade.png"));

//player we are wrapping
private Player player;

//parts of the editor player
private Shape shape;
private Label labelLbl;
private ObservableList<EditorPlayerAction> editorPlayerActions;

private FieldEditor fieldEditor;
private double radius;

private DoubleProperty editorX = new SimpleDoubleProperty(this, "editorX", 0);
private DoubleProperty editorY = new SimpleDoubleProperty(this, "editorY", 0);
private BooleanProperty selected = new SimpleBooleanProperty(this, "selected", false);
private double originalX, originalY, clickX, clickY;//need these values to perform drag

public void setSizes(double radius, double offFontSize, double defFontSize) {

    this.radius = radius;
    //create new components to reflect the resize
    this.getChildren().clear();
    if (this.getPlayer().getPlayerSide() == PlayerSide.OFFENSE) {
        shape = new Circle(radius);
        shape.setStrokeWidth(2);
        shape.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        shape.setFill(Color.WHITE);
        updateShadeGraphic();
    } else {
        shape = new Rectangle(radius * 2, radius * 2);
        shape.setStrokeWidth(2);
        shape.setStroke(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        shape.setFill(Color.WHITE);
    }

    labelLbl = new Label(player.getLabel());
    if (this.getPlayer().getPlayerSide() == PlayerSide.OFFENSE) {
        labelLbl.setFont(Font.font("Helveitca", FontWeight.BOLD, offFontSize));
    } else {
        labelLbl.setFont(Font.font("Helveitca", FontWeight.BOLD, defFontSize));
    }

    this.getChildren().addAll(shape, labelLbl);


}

public void setOtherBehaviors(){
    selected.addListener((selectedProperty, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        if (newValue) {
            if (this.getPlayer().getPlayerSide() == PlayerSide.OFFENSE) {
                shape.setStrokeWidth(3);
                shape.setStroke(Color.RED);
            }
            labelLbl.setTextFill(Color.RED);

            fieldEditor.getSelectedPlayers().add(this);

        } else {
            if (this.getPlayer().getPlayerSide() == PlayerSide.OFFENSE) {
                shape.setStrokeWidth(2);
                shape.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
            }
            labelLbl.setTextFill(Color.BLACK);

            fieldEditor.getSelectedPlayers().remove(this);
        }
    });
}
```